# How to crop a raster stack using multiple shapefiles in r

Tags: r, histogram, crop, raster, shapefile

I am new to r so I am still figuring out the basics. I am trying to a take a list of multiple shapefiles and use them to crop several rasters stack. Then use the cropped raster stacks and create histograms from them. 
I know I have to make lists of shapefiles which I have already figured out how to do. I also figured out how to individually crop rasters and make histograms.  Unfortunately, the looping is throwing me for a loop. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's what I have so far:

```
library('rgdal')
library('raster')
library('landsat')
library('ggplot2')
library('rasterVis')
library('spatial.tools')
library('plyr')
library('reshape')
library('reshape2')
library('GGally')
library('lattice')
library('sp')
library('maptools')
library('rgeos')
library('gdata')

   #Create folder for shapefiles located and rasters
foldershp <- paste0("F:/2926/Hayes/crp/hnw/")
setwd("F:/2926/Hayes/crp/hnw/")
fileName<-list.files(path= ".", pattern = ".shp$")

folderout<- paste0("F:/Indices/Histograms/")

#list for Rasters
ras.root<- paste0("F:/2926/July/")
ras.list <- c("mtvi", "ndsvi", "ndvi", "ndwi", "satvi", "swir32")

 #Loop
for (i in ras.list) {
  s <- stack()
  setwd(paste(ras.root,i,sep=""))
  files <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.tif$")
  s <- stack(files)
  for (fileName in fileNames){
    setwd(foldershp)
    data <- readOGR(dsn=".",substr(fileName,1,nchar(fileName)-4))
    names(data) <- substr(fileName,1,nchar(fileName)-4)
    m <- mask(s,data)
    setwd(folderout)
    png(paste(i,"_",names(data),"_hist_plot",sep=""))
    hist(m)
    dev.off()
    png(paste(i,"_clipped_",names(data),sep=""))
    plot(m)
    dev.off()
  }
    }
```

Comment: I would split this into two questions, how to crop a raster and how to histogram a raster. But see ?crop for a start. Also don't use assign, will try to answer just for code review

Answer (score 2):

I'll give this a shot, though i'm sure there are more elegant ways....

set environments, read in the shapefiles as a list of names, create a character vector of where the rasters are kept (in your case, "mtvi","ndvi" etc)

```
require(raster)
require(gdata)
require(rgdal)

setwd("/home/st/R/shapes")
fileNames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "*.shp$")

ras.fols <- c("one","two","three")
setwd("/home/st/R/rasters")
```

now loop through the raster folders vector, setting the working directory to that folder and make a stack of the rasters inside it.

Then the nested loop will call your list of shapefiles and, one by one, mask the first rasterstack by the shapefiles and save a histogram and plot image of the masked data.

It then returns to the original loop, moves onto the next raster folder and performs the same action.

```
for (i in ras.fols) {
  s <- stack()
  setwd(paste("/home/st/R/rasters/",i,sep=""))
  files <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.tif$")
  s <- stack(files)
    for (fileName in fileNames){
      setwd("/home/st/R/shapes")
      data <- readOGR(dsn=".",substr(fileName,1,nchar(fileName)-4))
      names(data) <- substr(fileName,1,nchar(fileName)-4)
      m <- mask(s,data)
      setwd("/home/st/R/write")
      png(paste(i,"_",names(data),"_hist_plot",sep=""))
      hist(m)
      dev.off()
      png(paste(i,"_clipped_",names(data),sep=""))
      plot(m)
      dev.off()
    }
}
```

hope there's something that can help. You can tidy it up, put the shapefile folder and character vector of raster folders to the top, replace some 'setwd9("adfad/asdad/asdasd")' with some tidier stuff etc

Comment: @Specks, so your root folder for where the rasters are appears to be "F:/2926/July/", put that as a variable called ras.root (for example). Now, create ras.list like you did.

Comment: @Specks, when you come to loop through each raster folder (to stack it and crop it etc), you want to set the raster folder dynamically using ras.list so you call the elements of ras.list 'i'. for (i in ras.fols) will loop through one by one those folder names, you need to then set the working dir as ras.root concatenated with ras.list[i]

Comment: @Specks, in this line "setwd(paste(listmtvi,i,sep=""))", listmtvi needs to be the root ("F:/2926/July/") and i needs to come from ras.list (in the code you pasted it's still ras.fols)

Comment: Thanks for dumbing it down for me. I did like you said and created a ras.root and fix the problems trying to setwd. But now I am getting:   Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: that error means something doesnt exist, and in this case it seems to be referring to a layer in a rasterstack. Could you give a bit more detail, like at what line the error occurs?

Comment: Since it spits out the error at the end of the loop I didn't know exactly where it occurred. I did a traceback and this is what I got :
6: .local(x, ...)
5: stack(rlist, bands = bands, native = native, RAT = RAT)
4: stack(rlist, bands = bands, native = native, RAT = RAT)
3: .local(x, ...)
2: stack(files)
1: stack(files) at #5 
I hope that helps.

Comment: @Specks, did you get anywhere?